# Drupal 7 drupal_move_uploaded_file ($filename, $uri)

Tags: php, database, file-upload, drupal-7, cpanel

I try to use the function `drupal_move_upload_file ($ filename, $ uri)`. It works correctly, but when I try to move file in the folder, it doesn't work. Permissions and settings are correct.

Any suggestions/troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to put the image in the public:// directory which is a URI or in a module or a custom folder ?

if you want to put it in a normal folder, try 
dirname( __FILE__ )
because it helps to get the absolute url.

Comment: Really, I had to move a file.php. The error was a function a Drupal, drupal_move_uploaded_file, which was deprecated in the new version of PHP. However, your answer is true, I had to try dirname(__FILE__)